# Getting error when trying to torch stack a list of tensors

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am trying to get cuda to work but I need to change my training input into a tensor. When I tried to do that, I am getting an error when I tried to stack a list of tensor into one tensor.

Code

```
for epoch in:
        alst = []
        for x, y in loader:
            x = torch.stack(x)
            #x = torch.Tensor(x)
            #x = torch.stack(x).to(device,dtype=float)
```

Shape of x: List of tensors

```
[tensor([[[0.325],
     [ 0.1257],
     [ 0.1149],
     ...,
     [-1.572],
     [-1.265],
     [-3.574]],
]), tensor([1,2,3,4,5]), tensor(6,5,4,3,2])]
```

Error I got

```
     22             alst = []
     23             for x, y in loader:
---> 24                 x_list = torch.stack(x)
     25 #                 x = torch.Tensor(x)
     26 #                 x = torch.stack(x).to(device,dtype=float)

RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Long for sequence element 1 in sequence argument at position #1 'tensors'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried `x = torch.stack(x).to(device,dtype=float)` as well but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tensor in your output is of float type with values to input your network with, second looks like labels (of type `long`).

Furthermore the first one is a `tensor` while the second and third element are `vectors` (with `6` and `9` elements respectively).

You cannot stack `tensors` of different shape hence this won't work no matter the types.

Unpack your `x` via

```
matrix, vector1, vector2 = x
```

To remove `type` warnings cast `vector1` and `vector2` to `float` via

```
vector1 = vector1.float()
```

Check their shapes via `.shape` attribute and act accordingly. 
**Probably though you already have batches of data as you are using `train_loader`**. See: [DataLoader documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) for more information and check whether you are using one.